# Linked list printing in reverse (or filling in reverse?)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

If I enter the input for this code as `1 2 3 4 5` then Ctrl-D to end the program, it will print

`0 --> 5 --> 4 --> 3 --> 2 -->` , which is strange. I tried following a tutorial for building a linked list but I think i've done it slightly wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list 
{
   int a;
   struct list *next;
};
typedef struct list List;

int main (void)
{
   List *start, *end;

   end = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
   end = NULL;

   while(scanf("%d", &(start -> a )) == 1)
   {
      start = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
      start -> next = end;
      end = start; 
   }

   end = start;

   while(start)                                      
   {
      printf("%d --> ", start -> a);
      start = start -> next;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

- I realise I shouldn't cast the return of malloc and should be checking the return of scanf! This is merely test code to learn how to build linked lists.

Comment: You are entering in the value for "a" before start has any memory allocated to it, other than the pointer size

Comment: `end = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));` should be `start = malloc(sizeof(List));`

Comment: haccks is right. find out why casting malloc is not such a good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: I added the line 'i realise i shouldn't cast malloc' because everytime the questions descend into arguments about malloc lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed entering the data into the list in a way that the most recent entry ends up at the head of the list.

One way to fix this problem is to make `end` point to the last *pointer* to `next`, and set it to point to `start` at the beginning. Note that `end` is now a "double-pointer":

```
List *start = NULL, **end = &start;
int a; // read data into a local, not into the node
while(scanf("%d", &a) == 1) {
    // Make a new node
    List *node = malloc(sizeof(List));
    // set the data to what we just read
    node->a = a;
    // This is the last node, so next is NULL
    node->next = NULL;
    // end points to previous node's next, so add new node to it
    *end = node;
    // Finally, re-point end to new node's next
    end = &node->next;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/SFBY9w)

Comment: and the *node? Very confused here

Comment: @Finlandia_C Don't free the double pointer. Go to the demo link, and see the last `while` loop to see how the list gets deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You have a memory leak here

```
end = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
end = NULL;
```

---

Your first `start` is getting lost.

---

You need to allocate `start` to `end` before you allocate memory for `start` in loop.

```
start = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
end = NULL;

while(scanf("%d", &(start -> a )) == 1)
{
   end = start;
   start = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
   start -> next = end;
}
```

---

I would like to add that, this is essentially *filling the link list in reverse*. Because the code fills the link list in reverse order from the beginning